# Terraform AWS (Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpn

I am new to Terraform but I have been doing good so far until I am trying to make a site to site VPN. I am trying to specify the inside IP addresses. Below is what I have. It all works fine if I do not try to specify the inside IP Addresses. For example if I delete the last 4 lines of code it works. Leaving those lines of code in their gets me the following error message:

'''

```
    Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with aws_vpn_connection.vpn_home,
│   on main.tf line 194, in resource "aws_vpn_connection" "vpn_home":
│  194:   tunnel1_cgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.238"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "tunnel1_cgw_inside_address": its value will be decided automatically based on the result
│ of applying this configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with aws_vpn_connection.vpn_home,
│   on main.tf line 195, in resource "aws_vpn_connection" "vpn_home":
│  195:   tunnel1_vgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.237"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "tunnel1_vgw_inside_address": its value will be decided automatically based on the result
│ of applying this configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with aws_vpn_connection.vpn_home,
│   on main.tf line 196, in resource "aws_vpn_connection" "vpn_home":
│  196:   tunnel2_cgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.242"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "tunnel2_cgw_inside_address": its value will be decided automatically based on the result
│ of applying this configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with aws_vpn_connection.vpn_home,
│   on main.tf line 197, in resource "aws_vpn_connection" "vpn_home":
│  197:   tunnel2_vgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.241"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "tunnel2_vgw_inside_address": its value will be decided automatically based on the result
│ of applying this configuration.
```

╵
'''

```
    # Attach  TGW to Edge VPC
    resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_attach_edge" {
      subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.subnet-01.id ]
      transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.demo_tgw.id
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.Prod-VPC-01.id
    }
    
    resource "aws_customer_gateway" "main" {
      bgp_asn    = 65000
      ip_address = "x.x.x.x"
      type       = "ipsec.1"
      tags = {
        Name = "House-test"
      }
    }
    resource "aws_vpn_connection" "vpn_home" {
      customer_gateway_id = aws_customer_gateway.main.id
      transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.demo_tgw.id
      type                = aws_customer_gateway.main.type
    
      static_routes_only  = true
      local_ipv4_network_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
      remote_ipv4_network_cidr  = "10.16.0.0/16"
      tunnel1_preshared_key = "###########"
      tunnel2_preshared_key = "###########"
      tunnel1_inside_cidr = "169.254.47.148/30"
      tunnel2_inside_cidr = "169.254.47.152/30"
      tunnel1_cgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.238"
      tunnel1_vgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.237"
      tunnel2_cgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.242"
      tunnel2_vgw_inside_address = "169.254.47.241"
```

Comment: Seems like the value ``tunnel1_cgw_inside_address`` should not be on your config file. Try to delete that value and apply again. You can't specify that value as terraform states on the error shown.

Comment: Sorry i added the full error message. Which is erroring out on all 4 lines. If i try removing both CGW Lines. It still fails.

Comment: But it's both CGW and VGW it shows error for.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [aws_vpn_connection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpn_connection#attributes-reference), the below arguments are exported by the resource & won't be accepted as inputs.

- tunnel1_cgw_inside_address
- tunnel1_vgw_inside_address
- tunnel2_cgw_inside_address
- tunnel2_vgw_inside_address

You could see the same [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/a842c8eb51738a4c575f2e2b1f9347f92d1f4b1c/internal/service/ec2/vpnsite_connection.go#L355-L357) in the code as these fields are computed on the fly & must not be passed as inputs.

If you remove above 4 arguments from your `aws_vpn_connection` resource, it should work.

Comment: That is what I was thinking the issue is. Unfortunately  the other end of the VPN auto create the VPN inside ips. And both sides automatically  pick the same IP :(

Comment: That's a different issue. This question is about TF configuration not VPN specific.